# Get image path : image is upload but not attached

Tags: images

my first question is ...

I want to retrieve path of an upload image. Important: The image isn't atached of any post. I have image url like:

`http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/sample.jpg`

And I want to get the path, like:

`/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/sample.jpg`

Thanks,
Marcos.

*I'm trying to improve my English. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very reliable in general (especially not in multisite environment), but for specific case it can be good enough:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/sample.jpg';
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$path = str_replace( $uploads['baseurl'], $uploads['basedir'], $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the attachment ID, you can just use `get_attached_file($attachment_id)` in WP Core which is reliable in general, unless you have some other plugin mucking with the uploads directory path